# Remove duplicates in Left join SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, left-join

I am having duplicates in end result. I tried using `Distinct` as well as `group by` clause.

```
Select distinct   
    Orders.OrderNumber, Tracking.TrackingID, 
    Orders.BalanceDue, Orders.Approved, Orders.Name, Orders.ShipCity ,  
    Orders.OrderDate, Orders.country, Orders.Shipping, Orders.CartId
from  
    orders
left join 
    Tracking on Orders.OrderNumber = Tracking.ordernum 
group by 
    Orders.OrderNumber, Orders.BalanceDue, Tracking.TrackingID, 
    Orders.Approved, Orders.Name, Orders.ShipCity, 
    Orders.OrderDate, Orders.country, Orders.Shipping, Orders.CartId
```

There are 8166 rows in Orders table and I want only that many columns in end result.

[image]

[image]

![enter image description here][3]

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us some rows from the two tables, and what "duplicates" you see in the end result? The `DISTINCT` always applies to **all columns** of the result - so if you have any difference in one of the column values, it's **not a duplicate**

Comment: I'd chisel off columns until you see no duplicates and work back from there.  But, I'm slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get one tracking id is to use an aggregation function *and* remove `trackingid` from the `group by` clause:

```
Select o.OrderNumber, max(t.TrackingID) as TrackingId,
       o.BalanceDue, o.Approved, o.Name, o.ShipCity,  
       o.OrderDate, o.country, o.Shipping, o.CartId
from orders l left join 
     Tracking t
     on o.OrderNumber = t.ordernum 
group by o.OrderNumber, o.BalanceDue, o.Approved, o.Name, o.ShipCity, 
         o.OrderDate, o.country, o.Shipping, o.CartId;
```